# Scope of Aggregation Functions when nesting apply(within())

Tags: r, matrix, apply, min

***Edited original post to clarify question***

**Background**
I'm learning R and saw this scenario and don't understand how R handles (what I'll call) implied context transitions. The script I am trying to understand simply iterates through each row of a matrix and prints the index of the column(s) within that row that contain the minimum value of that row. What I don't understand is how R handles the *context transition* as different functions are applied to the dependent variable `x`:

1. `x` (when defined as an argument to `function(x)`) is an *atomic vector* because of the `apply()` function with a `MARGIN = 1` argument
2. The `which()` function then iterates over the individual *elements* within the atomic vector `x` to see which ones == `min(x)`
3. **This is the part that truly confuses me:** Despite the fact `which()` is iterating over *elements* of atomic vector `x`, you can call `min(x)` within the `which()` function and R somehow switches `x` to be defined as the entire *atomic vector* again for calculating the `min()` across the vector vs. within the scope of a single *element*

*Example Data Matrix*

```
a <- matrix (c(5, 2, 7, 1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 6), 3, 3)
```

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    1    4
[2,]    2    2    5
[3,]    7    8    6
```

*This is the script that returns the column indexes that I am struggling to understand*

```
apply (a, 1, function(x) which(x == min(x)))
```

**My question:**

Within the `which()` function, why does `min(x)` return the minimum of the *atomic vector* (as is desired) and not the minimum within the scope of an individual *element* within that vector, since `which()` is iterating over each individual element within the *atomic vector* `x`?

Comment: `x` is anonymous function, lambda.  The `min(x)` returns the minimum of each row as the MARGIN here is 1 i.le. for row

Comment: `apply` passes entire rows to the function, one at a time. This is because `MARGIN = 1` (2nd argument). I believe this answers to both 1. and 2.

Comment: Side note: the construct `which(x == min(x))` is used when there are several minima; to get the index to the *first* minimum use `which.min(x)`.

Comment: `function(x)` is an *anonymous function*; `x` is the argument within that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: discussion about `which` and `x`:

- the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601961/scope-of-aggregation-functions-when-nesting-applywithin/62602961?noredirect=1#comment110707453_62601961) on your question is **incorrect**:

  > *`x` is anonymous function, lambda*

  `x` is just a variable, nothing fancy. `function(x)` declares it as the first (and only) argument of the anonymous function, and then every reference to `x` after that is referencing what is passed to this anonymous function;
- the code uses an *anonymous function*; normally, almost everything you do in R is using named functions (e.g., `mean`, `min`). In some cases (e.g., in `apply` and related functions), it makes sense to define a whole function as an argument and not name it, as in

  ```r
  ## anonymous (unnamed) function
  apply(m, 1, function(x) which(x == min(x)))

  ## equivalently, with a named function
  myfunc <- function(x) which(x == min(x))
  apply(m, 1, myfunc)
  ```

  In the first case, `function(x) which(x == min(x)))` is not named, so it is "anonymous". The results between the two `apply` calls are identical.
- Given that context, `x` is the first argument to the function (`myfunc` or the anonymous function in your case). With the rest of the `apply`/`MARGIN` discussion below,

  - `x` (in this case) contains the whole row (when `MARGIN=1`);
  - `min(x)` returns the *value* of the lowest value within `x`, and it is always length 1); and
  - `which(x == min(x))` returns the *index* of that lowest value within `x`; in this case, it will always be length 1 or more, because we are confident that there is always one element such that it is equal to the minimum of that vector ... however, there is no guarantee that `which` will find any matches, so the length of `which(...)`'s return value can be between 0 and the length of the inputs. Examples:

    ```r
    which(11:15 == 13)
    # [1] 3
    which(11:15 == 1:5)
    # integer(0)
    which(11:15 == 11:15)
    # [1] 1 2 3 4 5
    which(11:15 %in% c(12, 14))
    # [1] 2 4
    ```

---

`apply` works one or more dimensions at a time. For now, I'll stick with a 2d matrix, in which case `MARGIN=` selects rows or columns. (There is a caveat, see below.)

I'm going to use a step-by-step verbose function for trying to show each step. I'll name it `anonfunc`, but in your mind convert `apply(a, 1, anonfunc)` later with `apply(a, 1, function(x) { ... })` and you will see what I'm intending to do. Also, I have a `dematrix` function to help *show* what's being used in the `anonfunc`.

```r
dematrix <- function(m, label = "") {
  if (!is.matrix(m)) m <- matrix(m, nrow = 1)
  out <- capture.output(print(m))[-1]
  out <- gsub("^[][,0-9]+", "", out)
  paste(paste0(c(label, rep(strrep(" ", nchar(label)), length(out) - 1)), out),
        collapse = "\n")
}
anonfunc <- function(x) {
  message(dematrix(x, "Input: "))
  step1 <- x == min(x)
  message(dematrix(step1, "Step1: "))
  step2 <- which(step1)
  message("Step2: ", paste(step2, collapse = ","), "\n#\n")
  step2
}
```

## 2d arrays

I'm going to modify your sample data a little by adding a column. This helps visualize how many function calls there are and how big the function's input is.

```r
apply(a, 1, anonfunc)
# Input:     5    1    4   11
# Step1:  FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 2
# #
# Input:     2    2    5   12
# Step1:  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1,2
# #
# Input:     7    8    6   13
# Step1:  FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
# Step2: 3
# #
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
```

Our anonymous function is called three times, once for each row. In each call, it is passed a vector of length 4, which is the size of one row in the matrix.

Note that we get a `list` in return. Normally `apply` returns a vector or matrix. The return value is actually the dimension of the `MARGIN=` axes, with an added dimension of the length of the return values. That is, `a` has dims 3x4; if the return value from each call to the anon-func is length 1, then the return value is "sort of" 3x1, but R simplifies that to a vector of length 3 (this might be construed as inconsistent mathematically, I don't disagree).; if the return value from each anon-func call is length 10, then the output would be a matrix of 3x10.

However, when any of the anon-func returns is of a different length/size/class as the others, then `apply` will return a `list`. (This is the same behavior as `sapply`, and it can be frustrating if it changes when you are not expecting it. There is allegedly a patch in R-devel that allows us to force a list with `apply(..., simplify=FALSE)`.)

If we instead use `MARGIN=2`, we'll be operating on columns:

```r
apply(a, 2, anonfunc)
# Input:     5    2    7
# Step1:  FALSE TRUE FALSE
# Step2: 2
# #
# Input:     1    2    8
# Step1:  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:     4    5    6
# Step1:  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:    11   12   13
# Step1:  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# [1] 2 1 1 1
```

Now, one call for each column (4 calls) and `x` is a vector of length 3 (number of rows in the source matrix).

It is possible to operate on more than one axis at a time; while it seems meaningless to do it with a `matrix` (2d array), it makes more sense with larger-dimensioned arrays.

```r
apply(a, 1:2, anonfunc)
# Input:     5
# Step1:  TRUE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:     2
# Step1:  TRUE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:     7
# Step1:  TRUE
# Step2: 1
# #
# ...truncated... total of 12 calls to `anonfunc`
# #
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1
```

From the discussion of output dimensions, the `MARGIN=1:2` means the output dimension will be the dimensions of the margin -- 3x4 -- with the dimension/length of the output. Since the output here is always length 1, then that is technically 3x4x1, which in R-speak is a matrix of dim 3x4.

Pics of what each margin uses from a matrix:

[image: matrix, margins-1 and -2]

## 3d array

Let's go *slightly* larger to see some of the "plane" operations.

```r
a3 <- array(1:24, dim = c(3,4,2))
a3
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   13   16   19   22
# [2,]   14   17   20   23
# [3,]   15   18   21   24
```

Starting with `MARGIN=1`. While you have both arrays visible, look at the first `Input:` and see which "plane" is being used from the original `a3` array. It appears transposed, sure ...

For the sake of brevity (too late!), I'll abbreviate the third and subsequent iterations of `anonfunc` to show just the first line (inner-matrix row) of the verbose output.

```r
apply(a3, 1, anonfunc)
# Input:     1   13
#            4   16
#            7   19
#           10   22
# Step1:   TRUE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:     2   14
#            5   17
#            8   20
#           11   23
# Step1:   TRUE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:     3   15 ...
# #
# [1] 1 1 1
```

Similarly, `MARGIN=2`. I'll show `a3` again so you can see which "plane" is being used:

```r
a3
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   13   16   19   22
# [2,]   14   17   20   23
# [3,]   15   18   21   24

apply(a3, 2, anonfunc)
# Input:     1   13
#            2   14
#            3   15
# Step1:   TRUE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:     4   16
#            5   17
#            6   18
# Step1:   TRUE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:     7   19 ...
# Input:    10   22 ...
# #
# [1] 1 1 1 1
```

`MARGIN=3` is not very exciting: anonfunc is only called twice, one for each of the front-facing "planes" (no abbreviation necessary here):

```r
apply(a3, 3, anonfunc)
# Input:     1    4    7   10
#            2    5    8   11
#            3    6    9   12
# Step1:   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:    13   16   19   22
#           14   17   20   23
#           15   18   21   24
# Step1:   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#         FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# [1] 1 1
```

One *can* use multiple dimensions here as well, and this is where I think the `Input:` string becomes a little clarifying:

```r
a3
# , , 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
# , , 2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   13   16   19   22
# [2,]   14   17   20   23
# [3,]   15   18   21   24

apply(a3, 2:3, anonfunc)
# Input:     1    2    3
# Step1:  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:     4    5    6
# Step1:  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Step2: 1
# #
# Input:     7    8    9 ...
# Input:    10   11   12 ...
# Input:    13   14   15 ...
# Input:    16   17   18 ...
# Input:    19   20   21 ...
# Input:    22   23   24 ...
# #
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    1
# [3,]    1    1
# [4,]    1    1
```

And since the dimensions of `a3` are 3,`4`,`2`, and we're looking at margins `2:3`, and each call to `anonfunc` returns length `1`, our returned matrix is 4x2x1 (where the `x1` is silently dropped by R).

To visualize what each call of `MARGIN=` actually uses, see the below pics:

[image: 3d arrays, margins-1]

[image: 3d arrays, margins-2]

[image: 3d arrays, margins-3]

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation of apply() scope across different dimension sets. I'll be re-reading this post many times before I fully understand it :). My original question (even if poorly stated) is focused mostly on what occurs within the within() function. You call within(x==min(x)). Here x iterates over each element of the row while min(x) seemingly "pops out" to a larger scope of the whole row. How am I supposed to understand this scope switching? Is there a name for it where I can learn the explicit rules around when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

"Lexical scoping looks up symbol values based on how functions were nested when they were **created**, not how they are nested when they are **called**. With lexical scoping, you don’t need to know how the function is called to figure out where the value of a variable will be looked up. You just need to look at the function’s definition."**

**Source: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping